# What does the blue shield badge mean on Facebook?

Tags: facebook

I've recently started coming across a few Facebook users whose profiles boast blue badges containing what appears to be some sort of shield. These display on the  lower frame of the user's profile picture, as seen here:

[image]

I initially assumed this was related to being some sort of verification process, though Facebook's [Help Center article on verification](https://www.facebook.com/help/1288173394636262?helpref=search&sr=6&query=badge) makes no mention of it, indicating that the classic blue tick is the only verification symbol that exists.

What exactly does this badge mean, and how does a user get it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That blue badge is actually indicator of Facebook's profile picture guard. Using this guard users will be able to control who can download and share their profile pictures.

If a user turns on profile picture guard, the blue shield badge will show on their profile, and it publicly people will not be able to share or download the picture. In some cases it also prevent to take the screenshot of the photo.

**Note:** [This feature isn't available everywhere at this time.](https://www.facebook.com/help/756130824560105)

Read this [article](https://newsroom.fb.com/news/2017/06/giving-people-more-control-over-their-facebook-profile-picture/) for more info.

Comment: Wow, I'd never heard of this. Makes sense that they're only rolling it out to certain demographics in true Facebook fashion. Thanks.

Comment: Is this means that only Indians has this feature available? If so, why does my friend has it?

Comment: @TaufikNurRahmanda I've seen it a lot on the profiles of people in South Asia, that could include Southeast Asia.